# 'in-year' operator in FetchXml condition

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, fetch, fetchxml

I was looking for an 'in-year' operator in FetchXML conditions, but only found the ['in-fiscal-year' operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334216.aspx).

Is there a workaround for this functionality?

Answer (score 4):

The only Condition Operators [defined by the Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309405.aspx) for years that are not fiscal operations are:

- last-year
- this-year
- next-year
- last-x-years
- next-x-years

If you want a specific year (in 2008 for example) your best bet is to use the between operator:

```
<condition attribute = 'createdon' operator='between'>
    <value>2008-01-01 00:00:00</value>
    <value>2008-12-31 23:59:59</value>
</condition>
```

Comment: I thought so. Currently I set start of fiscal year to 1.1 of the year.